# Colors name for highlight the matched lines

Tags: emacs

When we use `highlight-lines-matching-regexp` in emacs and enter the regex. After that we need to enter the color for highlight.

I am getting only few colors, but I want some more colors, will it be possible to achieve this in emacs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When prompt for "colors" (faces, in fact), you can use any face Emacs have defined.  By default, a "hi-" is appended to the minibuffer text, so only a few are shown (9, in my Emacs version).  But if you delete manually these 3 characters, you will have all of the faces available.

And of course, you may add as many new faces to your setup as you want.

Example of face definition:

```
(defface my-silly-face
  '((t :foreground "DarkSlateBlue"))
  "Example face.")
```

Comment: any example of how to add my custom face?

Answer (score 0):

You can use library [**Highlight**](http://www.emacswiki.org/HighlightLibrary) ([`highlight.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/highlight.el)) for this --- e.g., command `hlt-highlight-regexp-to-end` or `hlt-highlight-regexp-region`, instead of the vanilla command `highlight-lines-matching-regexp`.

Then you need not specify the face to use each time.  (You can change the face to use at any time, using command `hlt-choose-default-face`).